# Export multiple series from highcharts into CSV

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There exists an official plugin to export highcharts data into CSV. However, I am trying to export data in following format where the number in X & y axis denotes the series number from which the data is coming from.

```
X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3   
1   2 3  4  5 6
7   8 9 10 11 12 
...........
```

Has anyone written a plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your code of what you have tried so far? People will more likely help you that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv export feature comes with highcharts, make sure you have the following references,

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/0k12prxL/1/)**